# Что значит знак "$" в данном примере и переменная n?

Tags: javascript

Имеется [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/arjwg98o/):

Не ясны следующие моменты со знаком "$":

```
n = document.querySelector(`input[name="${n.name}"]:checked`)

document.querySelector('.progress').innerHTML = `${notEmpty / required.length * 100 | 0}%
```

Помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так называемая интерполяция строк, там можно использовать такую конструкцию для создания строки `${}`. В фигурные скобки записывается выражение на js. Отличие в том что нужно использовать косые кавычки (`` ` ``)
Вот пример

```js
var name = "Андрей";
console.log(`Привет, ${name}.`);
```